# How I can make a select distinct for a year of a date field in my database cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

hello I have a date field en mi DB "dateToday" now I need make a selection of all year and store them in an array

2013-01-11

2014-03-12

2014-05-21

2013-11-15

2014-12-19

2014-03-17

2015-09-01

2015-04-24

my array will be (2013, 2014, 2015)

into my code I probe somthing but no found.

model

SoyaProductorCompra.php

```
   <?php
/**
* 
*/
class SoyaProductorCompra extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'soyaproductorcompra';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';  
    public $belongsTo = array('User');

    public function getYears()
    {
        return $this->SoyaProductorCompra->find('all', array('fields' => 'DISTINCT YEAR(fecharegistro) as distinct_year'));
    }
}

?>
```

but this no found in my view

SoyasController.php

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class SoyasController extends AppController
{

    public function cano($id = null)
    {
        $this->loadModel('Soya');

        $this->loadModel("SoyaProductorCompra");
        $years = $this->SoyaProductorCompra->getYears();

        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Porfavor provea un id de usuario');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }

        $user = $this->Soya->findById($id);
        if (!$user) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('El id proporcionado no es valido');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $user;
        }
    }
}
```

Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

File: SoyaProductorCompra.php

Line: return $this->SoyaProductorCompra->find('all', array('fields' => 'DISTINCT YEAR(fecharegistro) as distinct_year'));

Comment: Execute a select query against the table to return the dates in a resultset. Then iterate through the resultset and populate an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your **controller**, you can get the distinct years from your model like this:

```
$years = $this->YourModel->find('all', array(
    'fields' => 'DISTINCT YEAR(yourdatefield) as distinct_year'
));
```

Then, populate an array:

```
$distinct_years = array();
foreach($years as $year) {
    $distinct_years[] = $year[0]['distinct_year'];
}
```

... and set it to be available in your view:

```
$this->set(compact('distinct_years'));
```

Then in your view:

```
print_r($distinct_years);
```

Comment: I try it but i have error I edit my code you can see?

Comment: Yeah... when you're querying **from a model**, you don't put the model name in, e.g. just `$this->find(...` - you only put the model in when you are querying **from a controller**.

Comment: It isn't neccesary to do a foreach loop to format the array. You can use set::extract() to do it in a clean way. Also you can use debug() instead of print_r()

Comment: Cheers - put it up in an answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call the model inside itself, because it's stored on `this` variable. So:

```
public function getYears()
{
    return $this->find('all', array('fields' => 'DISTINCT YEAR(fecharegistro) as distinct_year'));
}
```